# A problem in compactness in Euclidean Space using a special topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathscr U$ denote the usual topology on $R^2$ and consider the topology 
$\mathscr T = ${$U$ $\subset$ $R^2$ | $R^2 - U$ is a compact subset of ($R^2$, $\mathscr U$)} $\bigcup$ {$\emptyset$}}

The facts I have found so far are that

$\mathscr T$ $\subset$ $\mathscr U$

($R^2$, $\mathscr T$) is compact

($R^2$, $\mathscr T$) is not Hausdorff.

I'm trying to show that if $A$ is a compact subset of 
($R^2$, $\mathscr T$) then A is a closed subset of 
($R^2$, $\mathscr U$).

The converse direction holds as well but I have shown that already, however, I have been struggling with showing this direction for hours. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is not closed in the usual topology, we will show that it is not compact in $\mathscr T$. Let $z$ be in the usual closure of $A$, but not in $A$. The family $\{R^2\setminus\overline B(z,\frac1n):n\in \Bbb N\}$ covers $A$ and consists of sets open in $\mathscr T$, but has no finite subcover. (Here $\overline B(z,\frac1n)$ is the *closed* disk centered at $z$ of radius $\frac1n$.) Hence $A$ is not a compact subset of $(R^2,\mathscr T)$.

Taking contrapositive, it follows that if $A$ is compact in $(R^2,\mathscr T)$ then it must be closed in $(R^2,\mathscr U)$.

Comment: genius!! Thanks a lot